# Transforming dijkstras to a* python

Tags: python, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, dijkstra, a-star

So, let's say I have some code in `dijkstras.py` that performs dijkstras given a graph G.

```
def shortest_path(G, start, end):
   def flatten(L):       # Flatten linked list of form [0,[1,[2,[]]]]
      while len(L) > 0:
         yield L[0]
         L = L[1]
   q = [(0, start, ())]  # Heap of (cost, path_head, path_rest).
   visited = set()       # Visited vertices.
   while True:
      (cost, v1, path) = heapq.heappop(q)
      if v1 not in visited:
         visited.add(v1)
         if v1 == end:
            return [('cost', cost)] + [('path', list(flatten(path))[::-1] + [v1])]
         path = (v1, path)
         for (v2, cost2) in G[v1].iteritems():
            if v2 not in visited:
               heapq.heappush(q, (cost + cost2, v2, path))
```

and G is something like this:

```
 G = {
                's': {'u':10, 'x':5},
                'u':{'v':1, 'x':2},
                'v':{'y':4},
                'x':{'u':3, 'v':9, 'y':2},
                'y': {'s':7, 'v':6}
        }
```

How would we transform the existing algorithm, `shortest_path(G, start, end)` to utilize a* with the fewest modifications.

What I'm thinking is:

```
def shortest_path(G, start, end, h): #where h is the heuristic function
   def flatten(L):       # Flatten linked list of form [0,[1,[2,[]]]]
      while len(L) > 0:
         yield L[0]
         L = L[1]
   q = [(0, start, ())]  # Heap of (cost, path_head, path_rest).
   visited = set()       # Visited vertices.
   while True:
      (cost, v1, path) = heapq.heappop(q)
      if v1 not in visited:
         visited.add(v1)
         if v1 == end:
            return [('cost', cost)] + [('path', list(flatten(path))[::-1] + [v1])]
         path = (v1, path)
         for (v2, cost2) in G[v1].iteritems():
            if v2 not in visited:
               heapq.heappush(q, (cost + cost2 + h(v2), v2, path)) #modification here
```

But I haven't even ran that yet, so I don't know how it's going to run. I just wanted to bounce this off of someone before I start to code more.

Comment: The cost cost + cost2 + h(v2) seems to be correct. This should be the only modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As alfa had suggested, the correct solution is to use `cost + cost2 + h(v2)`.